# Sync applications between several countries' stores

Tags: itunes, applications, ios-appstore, mac-appstore

I have a problem with managing purchases from different stores. As you know, Apple doesnt' provide the one global store for purchases made in different countries and some applications are published only in only local country store. Given that, I now have purchases in two countries and realized it's hard to keep track of applications, remove unnecessary and not used and so on. 
I decided to clean up my account and hide not used anymore applications. But it's a completely mess: something is downloaded on my mac, something on iphone, something on ipad, it all syncs in ununderstandable ways.

My question is: how do you handle this situation with different stores? I'm thinking about re-purchasing all applications in my current country's  store, but I got used too much to packaging managers and can't imagine doing it manually.

Comment: How many distinct AppleID are you using and have you switched any of these from one country to another? Also, what does syncing have to do with your question? I suppose you mean the one way download of an app from the specific app store to a specific device, but sync implies two way data exchange?

Comment: Single apple id, 2 countries.

Comment: About syncing: if I remove something at my mac but keep it on iphone I will get it back when transfering purchases from iphone to mac and vice versa. If I hide some purchase it will still stay on my devices and if I remove it from devices but don't hide -- I will get it downloaded again

Comment: It appears there are three questions here. I'll try to answer the main one and you can re-ask the other two as follow on ones if you wish (or don't get the answer you hoped for initially)

Comment: Well, right, maybe three, but my main concern is how to manage applications, looking for a general answer or best practice, not something specific.

Comment: If one of the answers has satisfied the query you had asked please accept it by pressing the Check mark bellow the rating of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I just got my new phone and wanted to sync to the backup of my old phone. The problem was with the apps. I deleted the foreign country's apps that were automatically put on the phone by the service provider (that I was never going to use anyway) and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to clean things up is to delete all apps you no longer want from iTunes and then carefully examine things the next time you sync.

By deleting the apps you wish to no longer maintain, you can avoid updates and installs.

As to the purchase history, hiding purchases and avoiding re-downloading is the only mechanism that Apple provides today to manage multiple country purchases against the same one Apple ID.

Answer (score 0):

I use to have the same problem, cause I had an account from my own home country, the country where I currently live and the US Store. What I did was delete all the applications from my iPod, iPhone and iPad. On my Mac I authorised the iTunes with all the three accounts, and then I applications that I wanted on each I synced, it asked me for a password if I hadn't used this id on the device and that was it. I still use it and I am not being asked for a password everytime.

P.S: I basically use the US store for most of the purchases, occasionally I use the regional stores if the app is not available in the US store.

P.P.S: I download and updates the app from iTunes and not the device directly.

Comment: Removing all the applications from devices isn't a solution. With such solution I would better switch to Andriod.

Comment: I meant to remove it for the first time only

Comment: I got it. But it's not a one time problem. After some time I will have different sets of application on my devices again.

Comment: When you backup your device, the various applications on your devices that are new are also copied, all you need to do is once in a while click on sync which will update the version of the application that is already on the device. That is you updated the Applications in iTunes before you synced.